# ajax jquery checkbox value duplicate

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I try to make a product comparison

1 / the customer check one or several compare checkbox

2 / when a checkbox is displayed, a message appears at the bottom

3 / the value of checkbox is stored under a session

step 1

The script below is in relation with an ajax. Every time I click on checkbox, it call the ajax but if I click on, I have a message, if I click another I have 2 messages, f I click another I have 3 messages ...

step 2

My goal is to change that and to have these rules :

1 / Select checkbox

2 / Message appears on the bottom with button

3/ Click on the button and all the value is inserted inside a session.

Currently, I am in step 1, now how to go in step 2, little lost with the js.

I suppose, I must remove inside the js the success
and include something like this

thank you.

```
<div id="container" style="display:none;"> 
<span class="alert alert-info"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="compare.php">Compare</button></span>
</div>

                $new_prods_content .= '
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $(\'input[type=checkbox]\').change(function(){   
            var chkArray = [];   
            $(\'#container\').html(\'\');

            //put the selected checkboxes values in chkArray[]
            $(\'input[type=checkbox]:checked\').each(function() {
                chkArray.push($(this).val());
            });


            //If chkArray is not empty show the <div> and create the list
            if(chkArray.length !== 0){
                $(\'#container\').show();           
                $.each(chkArray, function(i, val) { 
                    $(\'<p>\').text(chkArray[i]).appendTo(\'#container\');

                     $.ajax({
                        method: \'POST\',
                        url : "http://localhost/shop/ext/ajax/products_compare/compare.php",
                        data : {product_id:chkArray[i]},
                        success : function(resp){
                            alert("Product is added to be compared" );
                        }

                    });               
                });
            }else{
                $(\'#container\').hide();   
                $(\'#container\').html(\'\');
            }
        });
    })             
    </script>';

    echo $new_prods_content;
```

For information my ajax :

$product_id = (int)$_POST['product_id'];

```
if(!is_array($_SESSION['ids'])) {
  $_SESSION['ids'] = [];
} else {
  array_push($_SESSION['ids'], $product_id);
}
```

Comment: $_SESSION['ids'] = []; what is the expectation here . assign empty array  and reset  ids !

Comment: the reult must be on ajax : product_id[]: 12 product_id[]: 10 product_id[]: 9